# Autoencoder - encoder vs decoder network size?

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

I've been reading up on autoencoders and all the examples I see mirror the encoder portion when building the decoder.

```
encoder = [128, 64, 32, 16, 3]
decoder = [3, 16, 32, 64, 128]
```

Is this just by convention?

Is there any specific reason the decoder should not have a different hidden layer structure than the encoder.  For example...

```
encoder = [128, 64, 32, 16, 3]
decoder = [3, 8, 96, 128]
```

so long as the inputs and outputs match.

maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convention:

> The architecture of a stacked autoencoder is typically symmetrical
>   with regards to the central hidden layer (the coding layer).
>   (c) Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow

In your case coding layer is layer with size=3, so stacked autoencoder has shape: 128, 64, 32, 16, 3, 16, 32, 64, 128.